# PNG file in an ImageView shows up in "Design View", but not on phone

Tags: android

I paste `berlaar.png` in the `drawable` folder and then displayed it with an `ImageView` object in the `layout.xml` of the `activity` concerned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gp_tos_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/berlaar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Android Studio "Design" preview functionality shows the picture as expected. However, the picture doesn't appear when I run the app on my phone. I tested with a `TextView` object, and that shows up fine. By the way, it also doesn't work when I put in a preset `ImageView` object, like an `avatar`. I also tried java code;

```
public class Gptos extends Main {
    ImageView gp_tos_1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gp_tos);
        gp_tos_1 = findViewById(R.id.gp_tos_1);
        gp_tos_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.berlaar);
    }
}
```

but that didn't work either. Blanco page. Nor did changing the `namespace` of `srcCompat` from `tools` to `app`, or for that matter, to `android:src`. How can this be solved?

Comment: tools:srcCompat
use android:srcCompat or android:src .Tools is your Design View in android Studio.

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: check my updated answer. @CommonSense

Answer (score 1):

use `android:src` instead of `tools:srcCompat`  `tools` is your Design View in android Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gp_tos_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/berlaar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No, android:src didn't work either (see my updated question)

Comment: app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
remove this line and add wrap_content in width and height instead of 0dp

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `app` namespace i.e **app:srcCompat="@drawable/berlaar"**.

Using the `tools` namespace **tools:srcCompat="@drawable/berlaar"**, the image would only show up in the preview section as its function is to help you see what you're building. 
When you hit the compile button, the image marked with `tools` namespace doesn't get into your final build and that's why you can't see any image.

You should have:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gp_tos_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/berlaar"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/berlaar" />
```

If "berlaar" is a vector drawable, you need to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
  ...  
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true 
 }  
}
```

Comment: try using the `android` namespace i.e android:src="@drawable/berlaar"

Comment: vectorDrawables, isn't that for SVG files? This is a PNG file. Tried it anyway. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when this problem occurs, it's always because of one of the following reasons:

- The image you're trying to load into the ImageView is too large.
- The image you are trying to load into the ImageView is not a .png image.

## Image is too large

If you are loading the image locally, a quick fix would be to put your image inside *drawable-nodpi* subfolder in the *res* folder.

You can also optimize your ImageViews to load large images by adding this to the application element of your manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

## Image is not a .png image

No doubt, the best-performing image format is .png. But sometimes, we are faced with situations where we have to display a non-png image which are statistically known to render poorly (or not render at all). In this case, the best option is to use an image caching library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco).

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score -1):

The problem was "solved" by changing the phone I test the app on. Didn't work on a Huawei, but does work on a Samsung. That is indeed a terrifying prospect. If it works on Android Studio, there's apparently never a guarantee it will work on any mainstream, recent phone.

Incidentally, I changed the `namespace` back to `tools`, and it still works. That's because the `xml` `scr` or `scrCompat` attribute doesn't seem any effect at all, both on the Samsung and the Huawei. The reason the Samsung shows the picture is because of the `Java` code. The Huawei still shows nothing. So `xml` nor `Java` work for the Huawei. Sauve qui peut.

Comment: that is not possible, the tools namespace you used is just for designing. What were the android versions of the phones you deployed the application on?